# how can i create a dynamic map that shows our company locations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching for a jquery plugin that allows me to create a dynamic world map and mark the countries that we have a branch there in a different color or put a logo of our company on that country.
I need to have access to that map so when a user clicks on a country i can fire a jquery event.

i think Google has something like this but I'm not sure

Thank you

Comment: Google does have something like this, have a peek at their maps api: https://developers.google.com/maps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what is your intention. But think you may draw your attention follwings.

1. http://www.gethifi.com/blog/jquery-vs-flash-for-interactive-map
2. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/

   ```
   http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-basic-example.html
   ```
3. http://jqvmap.com/
4. http://jquerygeo.com/test/examples/events.html

These are the best I found so far